# How to check if an object is a certain type

Tags: .net, vb.net, object, drop-down-menu, object-type

I am passing various objects to a subroutine to run the same process but using a different object each time. For example, in one case I am using a ListView and in another case I am passing a DropDownList.

I want to check if the object being passed is a DropDownList then execute some code if it is. How do I do this?

My code so far which doesn't work:

```
Sub FillCategories(ByVal Obj As Object)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_Resources_Categories", Conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Obj.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If Obj Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList Then

    End If
    Obj.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 207, accepted):

In VB.NET, you need to use the [`GetType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) to retrieve the type of an instance of an object, and the [`GetType()` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx) to retrieve the type of another known type.

Once you have the two types, you can simply compare them using the `Is` operator.

So your code should actually be written like this:

```
Sub FillCategories(ByVal Obj As Object)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_Resources_Categories", Conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Obj.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If Obj.GetType() Is GetType(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList) Then

    End If
    Obj.DataBind()
End Sub
```

You can also use the [`TypeOf` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) instead of the `GetType` method.  Note that this tests if your object is *compatible* with the given type, not that it is the same type. That would look like this:

```
If TypeOf Obj Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList Then

End If
```

---

*Totally trivial, irrelevant nitpick:* Traditionally, the names of parameters are camelCased (which means they always start with a lower-case letter) when writing .NET code (either VB.NET or C#). This makes them easy to distinguish at a glance from classes, types, methods, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that code but actually the only thing is that it doesn't work with the '=' operator. I had to change it to 'Is'. The error I had when it was '=' was "Operator '=' is not defined for types 'System.Type' and 'System.Type'."

Comment: @Leah: Yeah, sorry about that. Looks like I should start paying more attention when writing answers. `TypeOf` is probably an even simpler option, at least in terms of code readability; I've updated the answer with an example of that, too.

Comment: There is an important difference between the two, which is what led me to this post. The TypeOf check will return True if the object is of a class that inherits from the type you are checking against, whereas GetType will only return True if it is exactly the same class.

Comment: _Totally trivial, irrelevant counterpoint:_ Even though the VS CodeAnalysis complains, I still feel the argument names are part of the public interface and so are PascalCase in my code.

Comment: Is there a performance difference between the two? - What about `Select Case (Obj.GetType())` with multiple test cases Vs multiple `IF TypeOf Obj is ...`?

Comment: Another point worth mentioning: when we need to verify, for example, the exact type of a MemberInfo object that we have through reflection with the type of an actual object, we can use something like:`myMemberInfo.DeclaringType.FullName = myObj.GetType().FullName`. That's because, like Leah mentioned above, we cannot use '=' to compare the actual types.

Answer (score 5):

Some more details in relation with the response from Cody Gray. As it took me some time to digest it I though it might be usefull to others.

First, some definitions:

1. There are TypeNames, which are string representations of the type of an object, interface, etc. For example, `Bar` is a TypeName in `Public Class Bar`, or in `Dim Foo as Bar`. TypeNames could be seen as "labels" used in the code to tell the compiler which type definition to look for in a dictionary where all available types would be described.
2. There are [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) objects which contain a value. This value indicates a type;  just like a `String` would take some text or an `Int` would take a number, except we are storing types instead of text or numbers. `Type` objects contain the type definitions, as well as its corresponding TypeName.

Second, the theory:

1. `Foo.GetType()` returns a `Type` object which contains the type for the variable `Foo`. In other words, it tells you what `Foo` is an instance of.
2. `GetType(Bar)` returns a `Type` object which contains the type for the TypeName `Bar`.
3. In some instances, the type an object has been `Cast` to is different from the type an object was first instantiated from. In the following example, MyObj is an `Integer` cast into an `Object`:

   `Dim MyVal As Integer = 42
   Dim MyObj As Object = CType(MyVal, Object)`

So, is `MyObj` of type `Object` or of type `Integer`? `MyObj.GetType()` will tell you it is an `Integer`.

4. But here comes the `Type Of Foo Is Bar` feature, which allows you to ascertain a variable `Foo` is compatible with a TypeName `Bar`. `Type Of MyObj Is Integer` and  `Type Of MyObj Is Object` will both return True. For most cases, TypeOf will indicate a variable is compatible with a TypeName if the variable is of that Type or a Type that derives from it. 
   More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/typeof-operator#remarks

The test below illustrate quite well the behaviour and usage of each of the mentionned keywords and properties.

```
Public Sub TestMethod1()

    Dim MyValInt As Integer = 42
    Dim MyValDble As Double = CType(MyValInt, Double)
    Dim MyObj As Object = CType(MyValDble, Object)

    Debug.Print(MyValInt.GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.Int32
    Debug.Print(MyValDble.GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.Double
    Debug.Print(MyObj.GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.Double

    Debug.Print(MyValInt.GetType.GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.RuntimeType
    Debug.Print(MyValDble.GetType.GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.RuntimeType
    Debug.Print(MyObj.GetType.GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.RuntimeType

    Debug.Print(GetType(Integer).GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.RuntimeType
    Debug.Print(GetType(Double).GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.RuntimeType
    Debug.Print(GetType(Object).GetType.ToString) 'Returns System.RuntimeType

    Debug.Print(MyValInt.GetType = GetType(Integer)) '# Returns True
    Debug.Print(MyValInt.GetType = GetType(Double)) 'Returns False
    Debug.Print(MyValInt.GetType = GetType(Object)) 'Returns False

    Debug.Print(MyValDble.GetType = GetType(Integer)) 'Returns False
    Debug.Print(MyValDble.GetType = GetType(Double)) '# Returns True
    Debug.Print(MyValDble.GetType = GetType(Object)) 'Returns False

    Debug.Print(MyObj.GetType = GetType(Integer)) 'Returns False
    Debug.Print(MyObj.GetType = GetType(Double)) '# Returns True
    Debug.Print(MyObj.GetType = GetType(Object)) 'Returns False

    Debug.Print(TypeOf MyObj Is Integer) 'Returns False
    Debug.Print(TypeOf MyObj Is Double) '# Returns True
    Debug.Print(TypeOf MyObj Is Object) '# Returns True


End Sub
```

---

EDIT

You can also use [`Information.TypeName(Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.typename?view=netframework-4.8) to get the TypeName of a given object. For example,

```
Dim Foo as Bar
Dim Result as String
Result = TypeName(Foo)
Debug.Print(Result) 'Will display "Bar"
```