# Is it possible to change a url column in a GridView (HyperLink or HyperLinkField) to a normal text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView which I export to Excel ([export gridview to excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094573/export-gridview-to-excel-file)) and it works.

But the problem is that the GridView contains a `HyperLinkField` column so its gets exported to excel as a `URL` while I want it to be as a text in Excel and not as a link, how do I do this?

The `HyperLinkField` column, in gridview, that I have is:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="learntable_id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/page2.aspx?learntable_id={0}" HeaderText="Learning Description" DataTextField="learntable_desc" />
```

### I tried to fix the problem with the following:

- First I gave an ID to the url column so I can be able to work with that column in codebehind so I replace the Hyperlinkfield with a Hyperlink like this:

  ```
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Learning Description">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlinkcolumn" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/page2.aspx?learntable_id=" & Eval("learntable_id") %>' text='<%# Eval("learntable_desc") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
  ```
- and in the Export to Excel code in page behind I try to `convert` that column to a text but I fail and I am not sure if I do it right:

  ```
  For Each gr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
      Convert.ToString(CType(gr.Cells(1).FindControl("hyperlinkcolumn").ToString, String))
  Next
  ```

But I can't arrive to change the link column to a text column, help please.

Comment: Do you want the link appears as link in GridView "Web Page" and text when you export it to excel, or you want the link to appears as text in both excel and web page?

Comment: I want to remove the links in the Excel file only. Thanks Emad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all links and substitute them with the text control.

Here is the C# code-

```
private void RemoveLinks(Control grdView)
    {
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        Literal l = new Literal();

        for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (grdView.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(LinkButton))  // or hyperlink
            {
                l.Text = (grdView.Controls[i] as LinkButton).Text;
                grdView.Controls.Remove(grdView.Controls[i]);
                grdView.Controls.AddAt(i, l);
            }
            if (grdView.Controls[i].HasControls())
            {
                RemoveLinks(grdView.Controls[i]);
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: it works 100%, thank you, I replaced LinkButton with HyperLink so thank you too for that comment too. If you don't mind, If I have 2 link cloumns, and I want to substitute only 1 of them, do you know how can I choose any of them to substitute?

Comment: You mean you want to display whole gridview on page but while exporting you want to export only one column. For this, you can create a datatable or dataset and a dynamic gridview with column you want to export. Then bind the dynamic gridview with the datasource and use this new gridview in your export code.  Also, dont forget to mark the right answer as it may help others. :)

Comment: Oh it doesn't work sorry, I notice one error and that is: `Compiler Error Message: BC30452: Operator '=' is not defined for types 'System.Type' and 'System.Type'.` I will check this answer and I will reply back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580044/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-certain-type

Comment: I replaced `==` by `is` and it works :). Anyway about the other question in my comment sorry I think that it is a question on its own. I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by JavaScript, remove the underline from Link by the Id or by assign Css class for HyperLink you want to remove underline from.

With link Id:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#HyperLinkId').css('textDecoration','none');
});
```

with link CssClass:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.HyperlinkClass').css('textDecoration','none');
});
```

**Update 1:**

You can remove the href attribute from HyperLink jQuery as well:

With link Id:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#HyperLinkId').removeAttr("href");
});
```

with link CssClass:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.HyperlinkClass').removeAttr("href");
});
```

Comment: I will test it and I will reply back I am sure that it is useful. Thanks Emad.

Comment: I am sorry Emad. It doesn't work I'm afraid. I tried to put each of those in a JavaScript function and call them in codebehind (of course in export to Excel code where I need them - instead of the code of the previous answer), unfortunately there is no effect. Thinking that the JavaScripts aren't being called I tested an alert and alert works but not your code. Additionally, instead of calling javascript from code behind I tried to insert those directly in code behind without calling them like this:

Comment: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyKey", "$('#HyperLinkId').css('textDecoration', 'none');", True)` and it didn't work. Unless there is another way to handle the javascript?

Comment: Did you make reference of jQuery in your page? `<script type ="txt/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>` if yes can you write the script into page and run it using button to debug the logic, and please look at the answer if updated it.

Comment: Thanks dear Emad I tried to install jquery locally too, the same, no effect. Please what do you mean with: to look at the answer if updated it? The debug output window does not show something interesting btw. I may be missing something to add something with the javascript code for it not to work but I'm not sure so if you happen to have a page discussing your answer that would be shed some light on how to handle it.