# In VIsual Basic how can I compare the types of two objects?

Tags: vb.net, object, types

I want to find out if two objects have the same type. I've tried

```
if TypeOf X = TypeOf Y
```

and

```
if TypeOf X is TypeOf Y
```

but neither of these are valid VB

Is there a way of doing this in one line, or do I just have to make code for each possible type?

```
if (TypeOf X is Type1 AndAlso TypeOf Y is Type1)
OrElse (TypeOf X is Type2 AndAlso TypeOf Y is Type2)
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an object is a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580044/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-certain-type)

Comment: x.GetType() = y.GetType().  Or x.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(y.GetType()).  Or TryCast(x, y.GetType()).  Hard to guess what you actually want when you don't tell us why you need this.

Comment: In my opinion, it's not a duplicate, since that other question is how to check if an object is of a particular known type rather than checking to see if two different objects are of the same type.  Similar, and helpful, but not fully the same.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Hans in the comments, if you need to check to see if two objects are exactly the same type as each other, you can do so like this:

```
If x.GetType() = y.GetType() Then
```

But, that may not be exactly what you need.  If you need to know if the one can be cast into the type of the other (x is an instance of derived class and y is an instance of its base class), you could do that like this:

```
If x.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(y.GetType()) Then
```

Comment: Thanks Hans and Steven. That answers my question completely. It's Hans's solution I need as I want to make sure which of an inheritance tree my object belongs to. But Steven's answer will also be useful later, I'm sure. I'd forgotten (or never learnt) about GetType.