# how to find different type of datagridviewcell or datagridviewcolumn (runtime created)

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcolumn

(sorry for weakness in english)  
I am working with-
window application, VB, VS 2012, .net F/W- 4.5 
I have a DGV (datagridview) in form. 
There are different types of column in dgv which are created runtime. 
To execute next step of process first of all I have to identify which type of cell/column is clicked (like dgv-combobox, dgv-textbox etc). 
Code is here, which is not working for me, So I tried to check type of clicked dgv-cell using MsgBox.

```
    Private Sub dgv_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgv.EditingControlShowing
            Dim column_type As Object
            column_type = dgv.Columns(dgv.SelectedCells(0).ColumnIndex).CellType
            column_type.GetType()

            If TypeOf column_type Is DataGridViewComboBoxCell Then
'code goes here       
                MsgBox("yes")            
            Else
'code goes here
                MsgBox(column_type.ToString)
            End If
            End Sub
```

But the problem is, control is going into the else part of the `if...else statement` all the time and  `MsgBox(column_type.ToString)` is displaying for all types of column which are System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell   or System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell. 
I tried to check column type using 
DataGridViewComboBoxCell,  
 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn,  
 DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl - but nothing works. 
I m not sure, but I think problem is with `Dim column_type As Object`. 
Please help me guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `TypeOf column_type` is redundant because column_type is actually a type! When you assign it to an Object, that's kind of wrong. You could just assign it as a Type. But even easier is to let the compiler do the thinking for you and use implicit typing

```
Private Sub dgv_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgv.EditingControlShowing
    ' cursor on Dim, it is Type
    Dim column_type = dgv.Columns(dgv.SelectedCells(0).ColumnIndex).CellType
    ' the proper syntax is Type is GetType(Type)
    If column_type Is GetType(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell) Then
        MsgBox("yes")
    Else
        MsgBox(column_type.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

The syntax is `If Type is GetType(Type) Then`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6580236/832052

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Option Strict on if you haven't already (project properties > Compile)

```
  If TypeOf DataGridView1.Columns(0) Is DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Then
        MsgBox("yes")
  End If
```

Works fine for me.

Alternative:

```
If DataGridView1.Columns(0).GetType Is GetType(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) Then
        MsgBox("yes")
End If
```

You are currently comparing typeof type to type.
If it doesn't work for some reason, you should inspect the code with breakpoint.